# BITS can't download with another URL

Tags: c#, background, transfer, microsoft-bits

I write a console program to download file by BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) and work well with url format as below.

**http://aaa.com/storage/file999.zip**

However, recently file provider change download url as below for security reason. Although normal user can download it by IE manually but my program can't download file by this kind of link any more.

**http://aaa.com/?key=8e3f1d258c3ca1106a681e14cad0aac&filename=file999&user=kkman&type=Y**

BITS job state will be **JobState.TransientError** when using this kinds of link.

I had googld but related info is few. Can any export give me a hand?

Comment: You could try uning fiddler, and see the actual url that is being redirected to and downloaded.